# tableCss style with Nested tables

Tags: css, html-table, css-tables

I am trying to set the first column of the outer table (**tbStudentPreference**) with special styles...

But the problem is that it applies not only to the outer table column but also to the table inside the outer table.

I want to apply my style only to the outer container table.  Please help.

```
<style>

        #tbStudentPreference td:first-child {
            font-weight: bold;            
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 100px;
        }

        #tbStudentPreference {
            vertical-align: top;
            padding: 3px;
        }
    </style>


<table id='tbStudentPreference'>
                <tr>
                    <td>xxxxx
                    </td>
                    <td>.....
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>xxxxx
                    </td>
                    <td>.....
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Inside Table
                                </td>
                                <td>.....
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Inside Table
                                </td>
                                <td>.....
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to set the first column of the outer table..

You need to negate the inner table.

Also, the browser automatically adds a `tbody` for you, so it is not enough to use a child combinator on `tr` directly. You need to override that with a child-combinator on `tbody`. You then negate the inner table by using the presence of `colspan` attribute.

So, you select `td` which is a `first-child` among those which are `not` having a `colspan` attribute, direct descendant of `tr` which itself is a direct descendant of `tbody` which itself is direct descendant of your `table`. Like this:

```
#tbStudentPreference > tbody > tr > td:not([colspan]):first-child {...
```

The negation pseudo-class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

***Snippet:***

```css
#tbStudentPreference { border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse; }
#tbStudentPreference td { border: 1px solid gray; }

#tbStudentPreference > tr > td:not([colspan]):first-child {
    font-weight: bold; color: red;
}
#tbStudentPreference > tbody > tr > td:not([colspan]):first-child {
    font-weight: bold; color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id='tbStudentPreference'>
    <tr><td>xxxxx</td><td>.....</td></tr>
    <tr><td>xxxxx</td><td>.....</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Inside Table</td><td>.....</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Inside Table</td><td>.....</td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: bravo, I didn't noticed the lackness of tbody element: +1